# "U1Conflict" Folders Appearing in Thunderbird

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-one, thunderbird

I activated Ubuntu One with the intent to sync just a few specific files between my desktop and laptop. I use Thunderbird as my mail client on the desktop, but Evolution on the laptop (no particular reason for the difference.)

I started the process by connecting the desktop to Ubuntu One. Although I haven't specified any email syncing, the Thunderbird sidebar now displays folders, usually empty, with names like "Archive.sdb.U1Conflict" and "Sent.U1Conflict". This is before I have attempted to connect my laptop. Viewing the ~.thunderbird folder and its subfolders in Nautilus shows no indication of syncing, and the only items in the Dashboard lists are the files I have designated to be uploaded.

Since I have no need to sync my email (and it may be difficult or impossible to do so with the different clients) is there a way to have Ubuntu One sync ONLY the files I specify, and NOTHING ELSE?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your ~/.thunderbird folder is setup to sync with Ubuntu One. You can see if this is the case by running the following command in a terminal session:

```
u1sdtool --list-folders
```

If ~/.thunderbird is listed there then you can remove it by taking the ID listed and then running:

```
u1sdtool --delete-folder=PASTE-ID-FROM-LIST-FOLDERS-COMMAND-ABOVE
```

You can tell Ubuntu One to sync specific folders, but you cannot tell it to sync specific files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the insight. I ran u1sdtool --list-folders and it returned "No folders" so I guess that isn't the problem. (Apparently you can't run u1sdtool "offline"- I didn't get any response until I signed in to U1.)

I'm beginning to think it is a Thunderbird issue, since I don't have the same folders appearing in Evolution (on the other computer). I know Firefox has a U1 add-on, but does Thunderbird? If it does, I'm not finding it. Until I clear it up, I'm using Thunderbird only for testing.